# Sql INSERT INTO ...values(variables seen as error)

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried this keyword and it works all the time, but this time mysqli is complaining about a specific variable in the values to add. I can't find what is wrong with that variable it just contains name. Sorry the question might sound easy, but am just a beginner and I can't find the solution.

> Payment Failed You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax  to
>   use near 'Okafor Iwolo', 'TP7487J', 650000, '2016-05-20')' at line 1

```
$sq = "INSERT INTO `Payment` (`ID`, `BusinessName`, `BankPaidWith`, `PaidBy`, `ReceiptNumber`, `AmountPaid`, `PaymentDate`) VALUES 
        //.....................!!error starts from this $pdb below, and its just a name $rn is letter+number $am is number $date is date!!........
        ('$id', '$bn', '$ban, '$pdb', '$rn', $am, '$date')";
```

Comment: Please use parameters, never concatenate SQL strings due to security. And you're clearly missing a ' after $ban, which wouldn't happen with parameters either.

Comment: missed quotes in `'$ban`

Comment: yes I know about the concatenation its just for design purposes, it won't be in the finally work. Thanks big-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your working sql query is below. you missed `'` after one parameter

```
"INSERT INTO `Payment` (`ID`, `BusinessName`, `BankPaidWith`, `PaidBy`, `ReceiptNumber`, `AmountPaid`, `PaymentDate`) VALUES ('$id', '$bn', '$ban', '$pdb', '$rn', $am, '$date')";
```

Change your query with above query it will works. your mistake you missed `'` after `$ban` variable.

Comment: so Stupid of me not to find this, I have looked at this a 100 times yet...makes me look stupid....Thanks big-time